# USB 3.0 PCIe 2.0 card in PCIe 1.0 slot, can I make it work with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: usb, motherboard, pci-express, ubuntu-14.04

I bought a PCIe 1x USB 3.0 card by Renesas, model µPD720201
to slide into my Dell Optiplex 990 motherboard's PCIe 1x slot.

Card: http://am.renesas.com/products/soc/usb_assp/product/upd720201/index.jsp

Board: http://clascsg.uconn.edu/download/specs/O990.pdf

Now, I know that the card I bought is of a later generation PCIe than my slot. I was not aware of the existence of multiple PCIe generations until after my purchase. Though, from what I can find on the web is that the later generations PCIe just increase the transfer rate. This leads me to believe that I might still be able to use the card I bought but not at full capacity, which is fine by me!

So the problem is that the card is being recognized by my computer, as seen in the following listings:

```
lspci -v

03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at e1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

and

```
lsusb -v

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.16
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.16.0-45-generic xhci_hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:03:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           31
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             4
  wHubCharacteristic 0x0009
    Per-port power switching
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           15
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

but when I plug something into the USB ports of the cards, no power is supplied and no connected device is recognized by the computer.

Similar questions like

[Should a 2.0 card work on 1.0 PCI Express slot?](https://superuser.com/questions/391466/should-a-2-0-card-work-on-1-0-pci-express-slot),

[Will a PCI Express x16 2.0 slot work with a PCI Express x16 3.0 graphic card](https://superuser.com/questions/786125/will-a-pci-express-x16-2-0-slot-work-with-a-pci-express-x16-3-0-graphic-card?rq=1)

and

[A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot](https://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot)

have answers that claim that the card should be functioning, even though my slot is of the first generation.

So is there something else that might be blocking the USB ports? Or do I have an exceptional card that is not backwards compatible?